# How to include CSS file in a Free Marker Template

Tags: html, css, jsp

I need to add a css file externally from a location to my .ftl file. I tried this,

```
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

is not working. And more over, when i used internal, the content is printing in the PDF file as it is.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried absolute path? If absolute path works, there is something wrong in your relative path linking.

Comment: I am gonna try the absolute path now.

Comment: @Nathan: I tried but fails again :(

Comment: Check the absolute path. Does it opesn the style.css? - @steeve

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure you're linking to the CSS file correctly?
Maybe absolute path can fix it

```
<link href="/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Depends on your file structure, of course

EDIT - note the "/" in your href attribute. signifies absolute positioning mate. or you can use "../" Again, depends on your file structure.

Comment: I am really not too sure if this is an answer or a suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The Free Marker Template default classpath, for static resources, is   `src/main/resources/static/`, as `src/main/resources/templates/` for `*.ftl` files.

So from a `.ftl` file in the `src/main/resources/templates/` access an external `.css` file, you should use link `href="css/your.css"` `rel="stylesheet"/>` while `your.css` file is in `src/main/resources/static/css/`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

May be this can solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

In my file structure I have:

> static
>   ...
>    -css
>       -> style.css
>    -img
>       -> img1.jpg
>   views
>    -index.ftl
>   ```

And it worked like this:

```
<link href="resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

templates on `/resources/templates/example.ftl`

static content is on `/resources/static/css/example.css`

include your css in your `example.ftl` template as

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/css/example.css'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/static/assets/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/assets/");
 }
}
```

this is a answer!!!!!

Comment: Sure? For an answer it has a lamentable lack of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use #include to link your css file :

```
<style type="text/css">
  <#include "css/style.css">
</style>
```

Comment: This is deprecated 